# 'cd' and other commands are very slow in my terminal

Tags: macos, unix, zsh

I am a **new** mac user and my zsh terminal takes a few seconds to open when I start it and commands like `cd`, `docker ps`, any `git status` take seconds to execute, while others like `ls` are super fast.
Could you please provide me with some guidance here?

Comment: If all commands caused a delay, I would suspect a fancy prompt (`PS1`). Can you give us more examples of commands "like `cd`" and "like `ls`"? If you can then please [edit] the question (do not respond in comments).

Comment: Have you done any customization to the shell environment, like installing oh-my-zsh or something that supports `git`, or whatnot? Also, what does `whence cd` show?

Comment: @GordonDavisson it shows "cd". and yeah I have oh my zsh installed.